# Convergent power series R=1

Tags: complex-analysis

Give an example of a power series with $R=1$ that converges uniformly for $|z|\leq 1$, but such that its derived series converges nowhere for $|z|=1$. 
I have tried many different series but can't seem to find one with these properties.

11. d) An introduction to complex analysis McGehee

Comment: Which series did you try?

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n^2}$,$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$,$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^n}{n}$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n.$  I am also a little unsure what derived series are. I am assuming that it is taking the derivative of the internal part of the series with respects to $z$.

Comment: That's not a bad start.

Comment: Yes, the derived series is the series obtained by differentiating your series termwise.

Comment: I am stumped I don't know how to adjust to make the series and derived series have the properties I need.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2^n}}{2^n} $$

Comment: So-called lacunary series.:)

Comment: Doesn't R=2 for this power series?

Comment: No.  You are thinking of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^n}$.

Comment: It suppose to be $|\frac{z^{2^{n+1}}}{z^{n+1}}\frac{2^n}{z^{2^n}}|=\frac{|z|^{2^n}}{2}$. So this fraction converges when $|z|<1$ and diverges when $|z|>1$ so $R=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing Stephen Montgomery-Smith's answer:

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{a_n+1}}{a_n+1}
$$
where
$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
> c
$
for some real $c > 1$

Then
$$f'(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{a_n}
$$

does not converge on
$|z| = 1$
by the
Ostrowski–Hadamard gap theorem
(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%E2%80%93Hadamard_gap_theorem).

Comment: It doesn't converge when $|z|=1$ because the individual terms in the series don't converge to $0$.  The original question is not about analytic continuation - its about convergence.  (I made the same error when I first thought about the problem.)